# How to select random sample of n lines from each file in a directory

Tags: shell-script, files, directory, shuf

I have a directory with many files. From each of these files I want a random sample and copy to a new directory with file names same as from which random sample was drawn.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p random_samples
find dir -type f -exec sh -c 'for n do sort -R "$n" | head >"random_samples/${n##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

This will look for all regular files in or below `dir` and will run a short shell script on these:

```
for n do
    sort -R "$n" | head >"random_samples/${n##*/}"
done
```

This short shell script will loop over the given pathnames (which will be regular files found by `find`) and will run `sort -R` on each of them.  This will shuffle the lines about, and the `head` will produce the ten first lines of each shuffle.  The output will go to the `random_samples` directory with a filename that is the same as the original file. No check for filename collisions in `random_samples` is done.

Instead of `sort -R`, you may also use `shuf` from GNU coreutils.

The only downside is that the ordering of the lines in the random samples will be random, i.e. the lines in the random samples will not be ordered according to their original ordering in the file.

To enforce the same ordering on the random samples as in the original file, we may replace our short shell script with

```
for n do
    awk -v OFS="\t" "{ print NR, \$0 }" "$n" | sort -R | head | sort -n |
    cut -f 2 >"random_samples/${n##*/}"
done
```

This starts with appending each line of the file with its line number (and a tab), and then we shuffle the lines and pick the first 10 as before.  Then, the picked lines are sorted numerically and the line numbers are removed before the sample is saved.

Allowing `find` to run this:

```
find dir -type f -exec sh -c '
    for n do
        awk -v OFS="\t" "{ print NR, \$0 }" "$n" | sort -R | head | sort -n |
        cut -f 2 >"random_samples/${n##*/}"
    done' sh {} +
```

To pick more or less than 10 lines, change `head` to `head -n NUM` where `NUM` is the desired number of lines to pick.